# How to build Curved HorizontalScrollview

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I would like to build a custom HorizontalScrollview that renders its items along an arc or a semi-circle path. I am not sure how to start, though i did think of overriding onDraw callback as a starting point. Can anyone help or direct me please?

Comment: Depending on the exact effect you're trying to accomplish, the quickest approach may be to implement [`ViewGroup.getChildStaticTransformation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildStaticTransformation%28android.view.View,%20android.view.animation.Transformation%29). Alternatively, one of the various Carousel implementations or ViewPager transitions may more suit your needs.

Comment: Ended up using a android Gallery widget, works ok, though it's deprecated in the sdk.

Comment: i want same implementation can u share you sample source or help me in any way ?@user2240193